# Does PHP have a built in function to insert keys before existing keys of an associative array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

For almost a year, one of our applications needed to check the values of an associative array and map a Boolean to a new array:

```
$original_array['key_1'] = $value_1;
$original_array['key_2'] = $value_2;
.
.
.
$original_array['key_n'] = $value_n;

$mapped_array = array();

foreach($original_array as $k=>$v) {
    $mapped_array[$k] = $this->checkIfValid($v); // Boolean returned 
}
```

I had no indication that the remapped version of `$original_array` would ever need to be multi-dimensional. However, the structure of the remapped version of `$original_array` (i.e., `$mapped_array`) was recently forced to change by our front end developer who needed a slightly different structure. Now, *some* of the members of `$mapped_array` need to be multi-dimensional:

```
$mapped_array['prefix-key_2']['key_2'] = $value_2; // note the value of the prefix_key and the key do not fit any type of pattern where you can write a function to generate the prefix key given the key
```

This clearly destroys the validity of the foreach loop. I know I can do something hackish like this to remap the original array to have a key structure that can be 1 or 2 dimensional like this:

```
$key_prefixes = array('prefix-key_2' => 'key_2');

foreach($original_array as $k=>$v) {
    if (!isset($key_prefixes[$k])) {
        $mapped_array[$k] = $this->checkIfValid($v); // Boolean returned 
    } else {
        switch($k) {
            case 'prefix-key_2':
                $mapped_array[$k][$key_prefixes[$k]] = $v;
            break;
            .
            .
            .
            etc.
        }
    }
}
```

However, I know the situation will get more complex as the dimensionality of the remapped array slowly increases beyond 2. Similar to concatenation with strings, where I can easily prepend/append to an existing string:

```
$original_string = $value;
$remapped_string = $prepend . $value;
```

Isn't there a function in PHP to insert keys before the existing key, thereby easily tailoring the dimensionality of a remapped array? Something like this:

```
$arr = array('key_n' => $value_n);// so $arr['key_n'] = $value_n

array_insert_key('inserted_prefix', $arr);

//Now $arr looks like this ---> $arr['inserted_prefix']['key_n'] = $value_n
```

Comment: `$new_array['inserted_prefix'] = $arr; $arr = $new_array;`

Comment: Let me re-phrase question at top

Comment: Not a single function. You probably have to split and merge the array with array_slice and array_merge.

Comment: No, PHP does not have a built-in function for that. You can find the list of built-in functions on [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/indexes.functions.php).

Comment: You mean this? `$arr = array('inserted_prefix' => $arr);` (same result as Alive to Die, but single statement).

Comment: I was just wondering if PHP had a named built_in function to do this since I had never encountered the need for inserting a key

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure wether I understand you correctly, so if I don't: please leave a comment below. But if I look at your (quote) 'hackish like this'-example, I think you are looking for something like this:

```
$mapped_array = array();
foreach($original_array as $level1key => $level1value) {
    if (is_array($level1value)) {
        foreach($level1value as $level2key => $level2value) {
            $mapped_array[$level1key][$level2key] = checkIfValid($level2value);
        }
    } else {
        $mapped_array[$level1key] = checkIfValid($level1value);
    }
}
```

Or even a recursive solution, so your code is future proof if more than 2 levels are added:

```
function createMappedArray($inputArray) 
{
    $result = array();
    foreach($inputArray as $k => $v) {
        if (is_array($v)) {
           $result[$k] = createMappedArray($v); // Calling itself (recursion)
        } else {
           $result[$k] = checkIfValid($v);
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
$mapped_array = createMappedArray($original_array);
```

With demo-data

```
$original_array =
Array
(
    [key1] => 8
    [prefix-key_2] => Array
        (
            [key2] => 10
        )

    [key3] => 2
    [another_prefix] => Array
        (
            [key4] => 1
        )

)

// Will produce (for a checkValid-rule 'value > 5')
$mapped_array =
Array
(
    [key1] => true
    [prefix-key_2] => Array
        (
            [key2] => true
        )

    [key3] => false
    [another_prefix] => Array
        (
            [key4] => false
        )

)
```

Comment: But ultimately the ability to insert keys for an "n-level" array requires a function such as "array_insert_key" - I was wondering if you could append/prepend key almost like a concatenation - looks like the answer is no and your comment at the top, incorporated into a while loop, would be what I imagine I would do

Comment: In that case: can you update your question with example-data of `$original_array`, and the desired result of `$mapped_array`? I read 3 different answers here with completly different understanding of your question.

Comment: OK - I updated my question - sorry, didn't realize it was confusing in some spots

Comment: I actually meant some demo-data of both arrays `$original_array` and the desired resulting `$mapped_array` (like I added to the bottom of my answer)

Answer (score 1):

For me the most confusing thing about PHP and its arrays is, that PHP arrays are no arrays in the "classical" sense. A "classic" array or list, is an numerical indexed list, with numerical keys, which make the whole structure ordered. So if you would have something like that:

```
$a1 = [];
$a1[10] = '##';
$a1[100] = '####';

echo count($a1) // 2
```

and

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($a1); $i++) echo $a1[$i]; //undefined index
```

what does not make much sense.

You can even go ahead an mix that with string keys like so:

```
$a1['key_1'] = '##';
$a1['key_2'] = '##';
```

And now the finaly question here is: How is that thing ordered? By order of insertion, numbers first than strings, by lexical order of keys? Honestly I do not know and I state that it will produce confusion if one tries to rely on that mystic order.

So my recommendation here is: Do not try to stick on the order of an associative array, create an array with an order you can predict.

What you are doing is: You have created an ordering with `key_1, key_2, prefix-key_1` and so on, connected to some values, which may be primitiv or complex, depending on the key.

So that implies headache, because it gets really hard to predict the order and adds arbitrary data types on top.

So to obtain a more or less predictable order you can do something like that:

```
$order = uasort(array_keys($yourarray), function ($k1, k2) { ..logic to create the order .. })

foreach ($order as $key) {
  $val = $yourarray[$key];
}
```

But than you still have to check if you are dealing with prmitive or complex data, so you could write something recoursive, if the data is complex, but seriously: **Take some time to refactor that code**!

To answer your question: No there is no built in function to insert one key before another, on a structure which maybe ordered.

If it is difficult to replace the whole code, you probably can exchange parts of it with something that behaves like an array, but it not. Have a look at [ArrayObject](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php), [ArrayAccess](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php) and [Iterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php) and you probably may be able to create class/object, which looks like an array for your code, but keeps track of the order on each inserting, iteration and validation.

Comment: Code base is 5 years old and responsible for generating a lot of revenue (i.e., cannot mess with our cash cow) - essentially impossible to refactor now

Comment: than: time for headache!

Answer (score 1):

Based on this example you gave:

> $arr = array('key_n' => $value_n);// so $arr['key_n'] = $value_n
>
> array_insert_key('inserted_prefix', $arr);
>
> //Now $arr looks like this ---> $arr['inserted_prefix']['key_n'] = $value_n

You could use this:

```
$arr = array('key_n' => $value_n);
$arr['inserted_prefix'] = array('key_n' => $arr['key_n']);

/* $arr is now:
 *     array(
 *         'key_n' => $value_n,
 *         'inserted_prefix' => array(
 *             'key_n' => $value_n
 *         )
 *     )
 */

unset($arr['key_n']);

/* $arr is now:
 *     array(
 *         'inserted_prefix' => array(
 *             'key_n' => $value_n
 *         )
 *     )
 */
```

There's no built-in function to do that, but you could easily wrap this in a custom function:

```
function wrap_key($array, $key, $prefix) {
    $array[$prefix] = array($key => $array[$key]);
    unset($array[$key]);
    return $array;
}

$arr = array('key_n' => $value_n);
$arr = wrap_key($arr, 'key_n', 'inserted_prefix');
```

Answer (score 0):

The PHP function [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) provides an easy way to loop through your array and process it.

For the original array your validation code could look like this:

```
function validate($v) {
    return $this->checkIfValid($v);
}

$mapped_array = array_map('validate', $original_array);
```

The validation function could also be anonymous for the one-level array. However, we need it to have a name for the multi-level array because it needs to call itself (indirectly by passing its name to `array_map()`).

In this form it is easy to modify the callback function to take into account that some values are arrays themselves.

```
function validate($v) {
    if (is_array($v)) {
        // Validate the array, return the validated result
        return array_map('validate', $v);
    } else {
        // Regular value, validate as usual
        return $this->checkIfValid($v);
    }
};

// The user code doesn't need to change
$mapped_array = array_map('validate', $original_array);
```

You can, as well, make the validation function described above a method of the class that uses it. In this case you'll have to replace `'validate'` with `array($this, 'validate')` in the calls to `array_map()` above and make the new method `public` (to let `array_map()` access it).